Extensión de VSC IntelliCode da error en entorno python
Al querer instalar la extensión de VSC Visual Studio IntelliCode v1.3.1  en entormo python el recomendado por microsoft  da error Se ha producido un error al activar la compatibilidad de IntelliCode con Python Si desactivo habilitar las finalizaciones de VSC para Python ya no da error pero no se que significa. Adjunto configuración y foto de pantalla


extenciones instaladas 
Pylance  v2024.8.2  
..... ...................  
Remote Development
v0.25.0

WSL

Remote - SSH
-----------------------
VSCode Terminal For Ubuntu
--------------------------------
Python
v2024.14.0
....
Python Extended
v0.0.1
...................
Python Indent
v1.18.0
-------------------
Python Snippets 3
v3.3.20
------------------
Remote - SSH
v0.112.0
---------------
Remote - Tunnels
v1.5.2
----------------------
Remote Explorer
v0.4.3
------------------
Spanish Language Pack for Visual Studio
---------------------------
vue-color
v0.0.3
-----------------------


 
  




{
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.fixAll": ["source.unusedImports"],  
    "editor.defaultFormatter":"vscode.css-language-features",
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/__pycache__": true,
        "**/.cache": true,
        "**/.coverage": true,
        "**/.coverage.*": true,
        "**/.hypothesis": true,
        "**/.mypy_cache": true,
        "**/.nox": true,
        "**/.pytest_cache": true,
        "**/.ruff_cache": true,
        "**/.tox": true
    },
    "[python]": {
        "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off"
    },
    "jupyter.interactiveWindow.creationMode": "perFile",
    "colorIdentifiersMode.tokenKinds": [
        "variable",
        "parameter",
        "property"
    ],
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {},
    "colorIdentifiersMode.manualColors": [
        
        "#FFD479",
        "#FF7E79",
        "#D4FB79",
        "#73FA79",
        "#73FCD6",
        "#76D6FF",
        "#7A81FF",
        "#7A81FF",
        "#D783FF",
        "#FF8AD8"
    ],
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Vue Theme"

}





Instalaste el pack recomendado de extensiones de Python? Dónde ves ese error? Por cierto, tal vez te está faltando un linter de Python, como Ruff.

Agregue el linter pero veo que no es el problema ..Por ahora solo con desactivar las finalizaciones de VSC para python que no se lo que significa ya no me tira el mensaje Se ha producido un error al activar la compatibilidad de IntelliCode con Python lo cual lo muestra al abrir VSC
